# How can I restart my python program that's using sockets?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a python 3.7 program that I want to restart, which wouldn't be much of an issue if it didn't contain sockets. Currently, my restart code looks like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=exec(open("handleServerRestart.py").read()))
os._exit(0)
```

where `handleServerRestart.py` is:

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
exec(open("Server.py").read())
os._exit(0)
```

where `Server.py` is the original file that I want to restart.

I'm using a separate python file to handle reopening `Server.py` because I thought it would help me avoid  `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`. I thought adding `timer.sleep` would give `Server.py` enough time to shut down so the socket would open up.

I am only using `os._exit()` because `sys.exit()` wasn't working on Linux for me. After I added `exec(open("handleServerRestart.py").read())` in `Server.py` `os._exit()` stopped working for me too. I thought it was waiting for `exec(open("handleServerRestart.py").read())` to finish so I added the extra thread, but it still isn't working. Any thoughts on something that could help me?

Comment: Why do you need to restart? This whole process looks very wrong to me, using multiple scripts and threads to execute. It looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @ThuYeinTun I figured it would be easier than resetting my globals. A little more future proof.

Comment: You need to enable the reuse-address option on the listening socket.

Comment: @AarushBothra Why do you need to reset globals?

Comment: @ThuYeinTun It just gives a clean slate for the clients. It just has to do with the way I made the server. Probably bad practice but I'm a beginner with about a couple weeks of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by calling `server.close()` to close my socket before opening the file with `threading.Thread`. Stupid mistake.